# Moving MS4W from Apache to IIS

Tags: mapserver, proj, iis

I'm trying to switch to IIS on my MS4W MapServer install.  It works fine in Apache but on IIS I get:

> msProcessProjection(): Projection library error. proj error "no arguments in initialization list" for "init=epsg:3857" msProcessProjection(): Projection library error. proj error "no arguments in initialization list" for "init=epsg:3857"

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly reference the location of the proj libraries in your map file, something like:

```
MAP
    CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "C:/apps/.../bin/proj/SHARE"
```